# Как записать в ArrayList множество значений и передать их в другой класс

Tags: java, android, массивы, arraylist

Я пишу приложения для андроида. Мне нужно передать значения для `ArrayList` из одного класса в другой, НО передавать не одной значения, а множества. Пример: у меня есть слова `"Hello"`, мне нужно передать в `ArrayList` не просто одно слова, а - `"H" "e" "l" "l" "o"`, то есть множество значений. Но проблема в том, что arraylist в которой я хочу записать эти значения, существует только в входных параметрах метода в другом класса `( 2 )`. Я не могу понять, как мне раздробить например - `"Hello"` на составные элементы и записать их в массив. Если я использую цикл, то каждая итерация вызова записи в массив, будет вызывать запуск всего кода класса.

`( 1 )` У меня есть класс - `MainActivity`, в нем есть метод (кнопка) - `onClickStart`.

Вот её код (без всего лишнего) - `out.setText(algorithm.mainMethod(new ArrayList<String>() {{ add(String.valueOf(str)); }}));` - это запись в массив `mainLine`, которой находиться в входном параметре метода - `mainMethod`

`( 2 )` Есть класс - Algorithm, в нем есть метод с входными параметрами -
`public String mainMethod(ArrayList<String> mainLine)`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 0):

Передать массив из одной активности в другую можно таким способом:

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
intent.putExtra("mylist", myList);
```

и принять так:

```
ArrayList<String> myList = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("mylist");
```

конвертировать слово в массив букв можно так:

```
String str = "HelloWorld";

ArrayList<Character> myList = new ArrayList<>();
char[] ch = str.toCharArray();
for (char c : ch) {
  myList.add(c);
}
```

либо передавайте строку и конвертируйте ее в символы уже в конечной активности.